# How I can register subdirectory of my vcs root as a bower module?

Tags: bower, semantic-versioning, bower-register, private-bower

I have this project structure:

```
- .git
- test
--- unit
--- e2e
- sources
--- lib
--- js
```

I have this project structure. This is some library, that I want to share with other peoples. I want to register my code as bower module, so people can easy use my library.

Actually, bower module is only `/sources/*` contents. I don't want `test` directory to be published in bower module contents. I want only `/sources/*` contents to be published.

Note, I know that I can *ignore* some directories like `test/` directory. After this when I do `bower install moduleName` I will got this structure:

```
- sources
--- lib
--- js
```

This is not what I want. I want to get sources contents.

Also, I tried to put bower.json into `sources` directory. After that:

- I have problems with `bower version <ver>` (no tags are created)
- I resolve full project structure, but only only contents of the dir with `bower.json` file

How to register bower module, so only contents of some subdirectory will be published?